# String Compare "Logic"

Tags: language-agnostic, string, comparison

Can anybody please tell me *why* the string comparisons below deliver these results?

```
>>"1040"<="12000"  
True  
>> "1040"<="10000"  
False
```

I've tried the string comparison in both C and Python, the result is obviously correct, I just can't figure out how the result is calculated...

P.S.: I know that comparing strings of different length is something you shouldn't do, but I'm still wondering about the logic behind the above lines ;-)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

"1" is equal to "1".

"0" comes before "2" (so "1040" < "12000").

"4" comes after "0" (so "1040" > "10000").

Answer (score 8):

The fancy word here describing this ordering is "[lexicographical order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order)" (and sometimes "dictionary order"). In everyday language we just refer to it as "alphabetical order". What this means is that we place first an ordering on our alphabet (`A`, `B`, ... `Z`, etc.) and then to compare two words over this alphabet we compare one character at a time until we find two non-equal characters in the same position and return the comparison between these two characters.

Example: The "natural" ordering on the alphabet `{ A, B, C, ..., Z }` is that `A < B < C < ... < Z`. Given two words `s = s_1s_2...s_m` and `t = t_1t_2...t_n` we compare `s_1` to `t_1`. If `s_1 < t_1` we say that `s < t`. If `s_1 > t_1` we say that `s > t`. If `s_1 = t_1` we recurse on the words `s_2...s_m` and `t_2...t_n`. For this to work we say that the empty string is less than all non-empty strings.

In the old days, before Unicode and the like, the ordering on our symbols was just the ordering for the ASCII character codes. So then we have `0 < 1 < 2 < ... < 9 < ... < A < B < C < ... Z < ... < a < b < c < ... < z`. It's more complicated in the days of Unicode, but the same principle applies.

Now, what all this means is that if we want to compare `1040` and `12000` we would use the following:

`1040` compare to `12000` is equal to `040` compare to `2000` which gives `040 < 2000` because `0 < 2` so that, finally, `1040 < 12000`.

`1040` compare to `10000` is equal to `040` compare to `0000` is equal to `40` compare to `000` which gives `40 > 000` because `4 > 0` so that, finally, `1040 > 10000`.

The key here is that these are strings and do not have a numerical meaning; they are merely symbols and we have a certain ordering on our symbols. That is, we could achieve exactly the same answer if we replaced `0` by `A`, `1` by `B`, ..., and `9` by `J` and said that `A < B < C < ... < J`. (In this case we would be comparing `BAEA` to `BAAAA` and `BAEA` to `BCAAA`. )

Comment: And, as a consequence of your empty string rule, a shorter string is "less" than a longer string.

Comment: @seh: No `B` is greater than `AB` even though `B` is shorter than `AB`. However, your statement is correct if you say that a prefix is always less than any nontrivial extension of the prefix.

Answer (score 6):

Think alphabetized.

Comment: To be specific, think `"ABCB" <= "ABBBB"`.

Comment: @Pavel Minaev:  are you sure?

Comment: I meant "think about what it evaluates to, and why".

Answer (score 4):

The strings are compared, one character at a time, from left to right:

```
10000
1040
12000
```

There's nothing wrong with comparing strings of different lengths.

Answer (score 4):

You're experiencing [*lexicographical ordering*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order).

There are [some generalized algorithms](http://www.elementsofprogramming.com/code/eop.h) for this ordering in the book [*Elements of Programming*](http://www.elementsofprogramming.com/book.html). Search for the word `lexicographical`.

Answer (score 2):

It compares the "numbers" on a character by character basis. In the first case, "1" == "1", but then "0" < "2" in ASCII (and as an integer) so it returns true.

In the second case, 1==1, 0==0, but 4 > 0, so it returns false.

And there's nothing wrong with comparing strings of a different length... but you should use the appropriate string comparison method.

Answer (score 1):

In C, string comparisons are done character by character. In the first case, the first characters of the stings are equal, so it comes down to the second character: '0' is < '2', so "1040" < "12000". In the second case, the first two characters of the strings are equal, so the third character is the basis -- '4' > '0', so "1040" > "10000".

If you want them compared as numbers, you'll need to convert them to numbers first, then do the comparison.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on the John P's answer, think of the strings as words, and read them left-to-right.

To look at it another way,

BAEA would come before BCAAA but after BAAAA

Answer (score 0):

It compares each character since you are comparing strings. If you wish to compare the numbers, then make them a numerical type.

Answer (score 0):

"10000" <= "1040" <= "12000" in the same way that "fabricate" <= "fact" <= "foolish".

Answer (score 0):

how about making them the same length?

That would unify numbers and alphas

1040 becomes 01040

01040 < 12000 now it makes sense

maybe that is why he felt it was wrong to compare strings of different length
when the strings are numbers they should be the same length