# Why doesn't this code sort lines containing numbers correctly?

Tags: c, pointers, function

I'm looking at this program that reads input lines and then sorts them, from K&R.

And I can't figure out why it doesn't sort them correctly if I enter for example

```
1234532 first line
abc second line
```

It won't sort them in increasing order. Basically it doesn't work if the input lines contains numbers or something other then letters, I think.

But this works for lines with letters:

```
abc
abcsda
```

will get sorted correctly.

This is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXLINES 5000

char *lineptr[MAXLINES];

int readlines(char *lineptr[], int nlines);
void writelines(char *lineptr[], int nlines);

void qsort(char *lineptr[], int left, int right);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
     int nlines;

     if((nlines = readlines(lineptr, MAXLINES)) >= 0) {
          qsort(lineptr, 0, nlines-1);
          writelines(lineptr, nlines);
          system("PAUSE");
          return 0;
     } 
     else {
          printf("error: input too big to sort\n");
          return 1;
     }


  system("PAUSE");  
  return 0;
}


#define MAXLEN 1000
int getline(char *, int);
char *alloc(int);

int readlines(char *lineptr[], int maxlines)
{
    int len, nlines;
    char *p, line[MAXLEN];

    nlines = 0;
    while((len = getline(line, MAXLEN)) > 0)
       if(nlines >= maxlines || (p = alloc(len)) == NULL)
          return -1;
       else {
            line[len-1] = '\0';
            strcpy(p, line);
            lineptr[nlines++] = p;
       }
    return nlines;
}

void writelines(char *lineptr[], int nlines)
{
     while(nlines -- > 0)
         printf("%s\n", *lineptr++);
}

int getline(char s[], int lim)
{
  int c, i;

  for (i = 0; i < lim - 1 && (c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n'; i++)
    s[i] = c;                                                         
  if (c == '\n') {
    s[i++] = c;   
  }
  s[i] = '\0';
  return i;
}

#define ALLOCSIZE 10000

static char allocbuf[ALLOCSIZE];
static char *allocp = allocbuf;

char *alloc(int n)
{
     if(allocbuf + ALLOCSIZE - allocp >= n) {
          allocp +=n;
          return allocp - n;
     }
     else 
          return 0;
}

void swap(char *v[], int i, int j)
{
     char *temp;

     temp = v[i];
     v[i] = v[j];
     v[j] = temp;
}

void qsort(char *v[], int left, int right) {

    int i, last;

    if(left >= right) 
       return;

    swap(v, left, (left+right)/2);
    last = left;

    for(i = left + 1; i <= right; i++)
      if(strcmp(v[i], v[left]) < 0)
         swap(v, ++last, i);

    swap(v, left, last);
    qsort(v, left, last-1);
    qsort(v, last+1, right);
}
```

Comment: What order are you expecting for your first example?  You should get the numeric line first, then the alpha line.

Comment: `qsort()` is declared (correctly) in `stdlib.h` - why are you declaring it again (and incorrectly) in your program?

Comment: I tought it was sorting them based on size; 1234123 is larger then abc, so i suppose the abc should be printed out first, not the line with numbers.

Comment: No, it won't sort on line length unless the lines are equal up to the end of the shorter line.  In your case '1' < 'a', so the comparison stops there.

Comment: @Chris: K&R use their own implementation of qsort: from the errata: *119-121(§5.11): The qsort discussion needs recasting in several ways. First, qsort is a standard routine in ANSI/ISO C, so the rendition here should be given a different name, especially because the arguments to standard qsort are a bit different: the standard accepts a base pointer and a count, while this example uses a base pointer and two offsets.* (http://cm.bell-labs.com/cm/cs/cbook/2ediffs.html)

Comment: That sounds just so illogical to me. I mean qsort should sort lines into INCREASING order, thats why i was confused with this. But i understand now, thanks!

Comment: qsort does sort lines in increasing order, but your definition of "increasing" isn't the same as everybody else's.  Why do you think it's more logical to sort strings by length rather than by alphabetical order?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is sorting them correctly.  Numbers sort before letters in ASCII.  What output are you expecting?

Answer (score 5):

What do you think the correct ordering is? You're probably getting confused by exactly what [lexicographic ordering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order) on strings is. From this perspective the correct ordering of

```
1234532 first line
abc second line
```

is

```
1234532 first line
abc second line
```

because `1` comes before `a` in ASCII. I have a previous [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1863028/string-compare-logic/1863137#1863137) on this topic.

Comment: Oh well, i tought it compared them based on length, not ASCII value. I guess that explains it.

Comment: Nope. It works like a dictionary with numbers coming before letters. Check out the Wikipedia article and the previous answer that I linked to. Feel free to ask here if you have additional questions.

Comment: If you want ordering by length, change `if(strcmp(v[i], v[left]) < 0)` in `qsort()` above to `if (strlen(v[i]) < strlen(v[left]))`.

Answer (score 0):

It does the comparison with `strcmp()`, so it compares individual characters. If you want to compare numbers, you'd need to add an option to (attempt to) convert as much of the beginning of the line as possible to a number and compare the converted numbers when you do the sort (and decide how to treat lines that start with anything other than a digit).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to sort strictly on line length, you'll need to make a comparison function to do that and pass it to qsort().