# Angular Material table sorting list of IPs

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

[Example here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1delje-xl6bui?file=src/app/table-sorting-example.ts)

I'm not sure why Material Table sorting doesn't order the table correctly I made an example stackblitz there.

(Expected) Sorted lowest IP first

```
"10.16.0.8"
"10.16.0.16"
"10.16.0.32"
"10.16.10.35"
"10.16.10.64"
"10.16.10.120"
```

(Expected) Then you click button to sort highest and you'd get

```
"10.16.10.120"
"10.16.10.64"
"10.16.10.35"
"10.16.0.32"
"10.16.0.16"
"10.16.0.8"
```

But the current output when sorting now can be :

```
10.16.0.16
10.16.0.32
10.16.0.8
10.16.10.120
10.16.10.35
10.16.10.64
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need take account that you're orderer alphabetical (120 is less than 9), so you need transform yours IPs to get the same numbers of digits

```
  ipsnormalized = this.ips    //create a string separated by dots each number
                              //three digits, eg. 1.23.9.10 =>001.023.009.010
    .map(x => x.split("."))
    .map((x: string[]) => {
      return x.map(y => ("000" + y).slice(-3)).join(".");
    })
    .sort()                  //sort
    .map(x => x.split("."))  //remove the "0s"
    .map((x: string[]) => {
      return x.map(y => +y).join(".");
    });
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-qeszwu?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

**Updated** to sort a Mat-table, only add a new property to your data

```
  element = ELEMENT_DATA.map((x: any) => ({
    ...x,
    normalize: x.weight
      .split(".")
      .map((y: string[]) => ("000" + y).slice(-3))
      .join(".")
  }));
  dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.element);
```

And indicate to header this property to sort, (this `mat-sort-header="normalize"`)

```html
    <ng-container matColumnDef="weight" >
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header="normalize"> Weight</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.weight}} </td>
      </ng-container>
```

A [new stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1delje-vkwsff?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftable-sorting-example.ts)

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for the help!

Comment: Amazing! This is a really nice fix, I'd have never thought of it.

Answer (score 0):

Sorting is done by comparing strings, same as Java, its in "lexicographical order", you can find more in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1863028/string-compare-logic)

If you want to sort them by number value, you need to remove the dots, and sort them while still showing the dots in the view.