# Sorting Object's Attribute Angular Material

Tags: html, angular, angular-material, mat-table

I am trying to sort a mat-table using the mat-sort-header. I am able to do it with common attributes like string or number.

```
 <table #tablaClientes mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort multiTemplateDataRows>
  <!-- Id Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="idIngreso">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Id Comprobante</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">{{row.idIngreso}}</td>
  </ng-container>
  <!-- Proveedor Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="idProveedor">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Nombre Proveedor</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">{{row.idProveedor.nombre}}</td>
  </ng-container>
  <!-- Fecha Compra Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="fechaCompra">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Fecha de Compra</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">{{row.fechaCompra}}</td>
  </ng-container>
  <!-- Fecha Recepcion Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="fechaRecepcion">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Fecha de Recepcion</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">{{row.fechaRecepcion}}</td>
  </ng-container>
  <!-- Monto Total Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="totalIngreso">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Monto Total</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">{{row.totalIngreso |currency}}</td>
  </ng-container>
```

However I can't sort by **idProveedor** since it's an object.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

The easer way is add to your dataSource a new property and sort by this new property like [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64968027/angular-material-table-sorting-list-of-ips/64968344#64968344) (really if you don't need the "idProveedor" object, your dataSource can be transform to some like

```
this.data.forEach(x=>{
   x.proveedorNombre=x.idProveedor.nombre
   delete x.idProveedor
}
```

Another solution is create a sortingDataAccesor

```
this.dataSource.sortingDataAccessor = (item, property) => {
     if (property=="idProveedor")
         return item.nombre;
     if (property=="idIngreso")
        return item.idIngreso
     if (property=="fechaCompra")
        return item.fechaCompra

     ...
}
```

An example simple in [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-acl4w2?file=src/app/table-sorting-example.ts)