# PrimeNG data table: Issue while sorting a date column

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, primeng

I am using PrimeNG Data table,
table has multiple columns, one of them is date column with date format like 'DD MMM YYYY, hh:mm'
How can I sort by date a column without changing date format? I assume it sorts by its string value because it doesn't sort correctly,

Is there any workaround or fix for this issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about PrimeNG but I think that you can have two properties date and dateToSort (dateToSort is the date in format `YYYYMMDD` and indicate that the column to order is dateToSort

```
<ng-template pTemplate="header" let-columns>
  <tr>
    <th *ngFor="let col of columns" 
        [pSortableColumn]="col.field=="date"?"datesort":col.field">
                {{col.header}}
        <p-sortIcon [field]="col.field"></p-sortIcon>
    </th>
  </tr>
</ng-template>
```

Some looks like in [this SO about material table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64968027/angular-material-table-sorting-list-of-ips/64968344#64968344)