# Ho can I sort large integer displayed with comma(ex: 54,45,444) in a column with mat sort

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular9

I am not able to sort the column in Mat Table with mat sort having numbers displayed . The numbers returning from the api are comma separated at hundreds , thousands places and so on.

Html

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="amount">
  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Amount </th>
  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.amount}} </td>
  <td mat-footer-cell *matFooterCellDef> </td>
</ng-container>
```

.Ts

```
displayedColumns: string[] = ['amount', 'name'];

@ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;

ngOnInit(){
  this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
}
ngAfterViewInit(){
  this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
};
```

Comment: Hello. You can sort your data before send it to the table.

data.sort((a.b) => a - b)

Answer (score 0):

The numbers should be numbers. Use the service to return numbers instead strings using map. e.g. If your property is "amount" you can use your service

```
getData(id){
  return this.httpClient.get(...).pipe(
    map((x:any)=>({...x,amount:+amount.replace(',','')}))
  )
}
getList(){
  return this.httpClient.get(...).pipe(
    map((res:any[])=>
      return res.map(x=>({...x,amount:+amount.replace(',','')}))
    )
}
```

Then you can use number pipe to show the number formatted in your table

The other option is add a new property that was number and use this property to sort like this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64968027/angular-material-table-sorting-list-of-ips/64968344#64968344) (in this SO is used this tecnica to order IPs)