# Angular 17 mat-table with sort on complicated data structure

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular-material-table

Mat-Table will not sort data

I all I am having trouble getting `matSort` to work on header (`mat-sort-header`).

The table headers show the arrows when I click them, and the data doesn't sort.

I have a complicated data structure so I am setting the `mat-cell` data with a method ex.(below).

```
//An Example column('name') not actual data structure but should get my point across
a(row, num){
  if(num == 1) { return row[0].typeA.nameObj; }
  if(num == 2) { return row[0].typeb.Something.dragonName; }
  return '';
}
```

I tried to follow the same kind of set up shown in this but doesnt seem to work with my table.
(https://stackblitz.com/run?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftable-overview-example.ts)`

I tried to use sortingDataAccessor but not sure I am using it correctly.

```
this.dataSource.sortingDataAccessor = (item, property) => {
        switch(property) {
          case 'name': return a(item, property);
          case 'title' : return methodHere();
          case 'desc' : return methodHere();
          default: return item[property];
        }
      };
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your link not work, and you don't show an example of your data, so, as general idea, take a llok to this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64968027/angular-material-table-sorting-list-of-ips/64968344#64968344) as inspiration. In this, you add a "new column" (really you add a new property  to each object in the array) and indicate in the sort of the column the "really property" you use to sort.